# JPA class not found on production system

Tags: eclipse, jpa, classnotfoundexception

I am using eclipse mars and seem to be able to use JPA in a stand alone app (no glassfish/jboss) by just using these libraries:

1. eclipselink.jar
2. javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
3. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar

But when I build and deploy my app I keep getting the below errors. Would my version of java matter? I'm using 1.6.0 24 32 bit on my production board and my IDE is a 64 bit system. The above libraries were included when I created a test project in NetBeans so I was able to use JPA in NetBeans fine as well. Am I missing additional libraries or perhaps something is wrong with my deployment? any advise is greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NoResultException
    at com.s3.utils.ExceptionCatchingSwingWorker$1.done(ExceptionCatchingSwingWorker.java:79)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.s3.gui.control.TracingEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TracingEventQueue.java:30)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NoResultException
    at com.s3.gui.pages.usermanagement.ImportFromUSBActionListener.doInstall(ImportFromUSBActionListener.java:116)
```

Comment: are you including your jpa implementation on your bunde jar/war or it's provided ?

Comment: I believe we will need to provide the implementation libraries our selves since we are not using a J2EE app server hence my attempting to package the eclipselink and javax.persistence jars with our app. While creating a deployment bundle of our app we package other jars into a thirdparty.jar which I believe is created in the build by taking all the contents of dependent jars and placing them into the thirdparty jar. I'll double check that with my team his morning.

Comment: Yes, you will need to provide the implementation and all libraries required to execute your app